# import mocha unit tests result in sonarqube

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sonarqube, mocha.js

I use mocha to get unit tests results and istanbul to get code coverage. I'm using grunt to run these tasks. It works fine. I'm also using `grunt-sonar-runner`plugin to import these result in sonar. Currently code coverage is imported but that is not the case for unit tests results. During the build, sonar report me this :

```
20:40:19.410 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "Account Controllers User Controller forgot password", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "Account Controllers User Controller forgot password.js"
20:40:19.411 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "Account Controllers User Controller login", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "Account Controllers User Controller login.js"
20:40:19.413 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "Account Controllers User Controller logout", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "Account Controllers User Controller logout.js"
```

Because of this, sonar don't save unit tests results. I tryed to change the javascript plugin version in 2.2, or upgrade sonar system in 5.1.1 but the problem is the same. I also try to rename all `describe` function to form the right path to the file with `.` between folders (e.g: `test.unit.controllers.filename.` And I realized that it works for only one test. If you have more than 1 tests, it will not work.

configuration:
* sonar (4.5.2)
* javascript plugin (2.7)

npm modules:
* mocha-sonar-reporter (^0.1.3)
* mocha: (^2.1.0)
* grunt-mocha-test (^0.12.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually get code coverage with istanbul and unit tests results with mocha. Indeed, the mocha (xunit reporter) fails. It only works if you have one test and a classname correctly set with `.` between folders and filename. 
Here is the solution with mocha and grunt, please follow exactly these steps and respect naming of files and folders :
1. Use npm module : `sonar-mocha-reporter`
2. Add these lines in your package.json:

```
    "config": {
        "mocha-sonar-reporter": {
            "classname": "Test",
            "testdir": "test",
            "outputfile": "report/TEST-results.xml"
        }
    }
```

3. Define npm test cmd (I defined a grunt task to run test with grunt `mocha-test` plugin ):

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt runTests"
    }
```

4. Define the grunt task:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

        grunt.config.set('mochaTest', {
            test: {
                options: {
                    timeout:           6000,
                    reporter:          'mocha-sonar-reporter',
                    quiet:             false,
                    clearRequireCache: true
                },
                src:     ['test/**/*.js']
            }
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    };
```

5. Configure your reporting with grunt `sonar-runner` plugin and add these lines if it not already the case (options object):

```
   dynamicAnalysis: 'reuseReports',
   tests: 'test',
   javascript: {
       jstestdriver: {
           reportsPath: 'report'
       },
       lcov: {
           reportPath: 'report/lcov.info'
       }
   },
```

6. Run your test with `npm test` command. with `grunt` or `gulp`,  it won't work.

configuration:
* sonar (4.5.2)
* javascript plugin (2.7)

npm modules:
* mocha-sonar-reporter (^0.1.3)
* mocha: (^2.1.0)
* grunt-mocha-test (^0.12.7)

Useful documentation which helped me to solve this problem : [sonarqube javascript plugin docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Unit+Tests+Execution+Reports+Import)

Answer (score 3):

In a node app I solve this problem doing the steps bellow:

First: In **package.json** file, I included this line:

```
"scripts": {  
    ...,  
    ...,  
    "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov mocha test/*/*.js"  
},
```

Second: Install **nyc**

```
npm install nyc --save-dev
```

Last: Run **sonar-scanner**

I created an example in a repo for this case:

https://github.com/macielbombonato/docker-sonar/blob/master/tools/scripts/scanner-npm.sh

I hope this can help.

Comment: nyc is coverage, not test result data.

Answer (score 1):

I am using using Bamboo for CI + SonarQube, so this answer (for NodeJS) combines both, to have visibility in Bamboo for test reports and in SonarQube for test execution visibility and code coverage visibility:

- `yarn add -D mocha-bamboo-reporter mocha-multi-reporters mocha-sonarqube-reporter`
- `sonar-project.properties`:

```
# this is for code coverage
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
# this is for test reports
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/test_results.xml
```

- `package.json`:

```
    "testWithCoverage": "nyc -r lcov -e .ts -x \"*.test.ts\" mocha --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=mocha-multi-config.json -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts && nyc report",
```

- `mocha-multi-config.json`:

```
{
  "reporterEnabled": "mocha-bamboo-reporter, mocha-sonarqube-reporter",
  "mochaSonarqubeReporterReporterOptions": {
    "output": "coverage/test_results.xml"
  },
  "mochaBambooReporterReporterOptions": {
    "output": "coverage/mocha.json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Node & Mocha project I have resolved this issue by doing following steps.(This solution will resolve 0% coverage issue and not showing unit tests issue in sonar)

1. npm install mocha-sonarqube-reporter (it will generate xunit.xml file)
2. npm install sonar-scanner
3. Add below lines in package.json

   ```
    "scripts"{
        ...,
        ...,
        "test": "env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' nyc mocha -r ts-node/register 'test/**/*.ts'  --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --exit",
        "coverage": "nyc --reporter=lcov npm run test --exit",
        "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
         }
   ```
4. Include below lines in sonar-project.properties file.

   sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths = coverage/lcov.info
   sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths=xunit.xml
5. npm run coverage
6. npm run sonar